# Jquery show one div and hide another div

Tags: jquery

I am making a navigation were i need some different things showed on click. But only one tab should be showed at a time. Im not pro jquery, so was hoping someone can tell me what i done wrong?

I need my login box showed when i enter my site, but when i push new user, login box should slide up and then new user box should slide down.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
  <a id="logmein" href="#">login</a>
  <a id="createme" href="#">new user</a>

  <div id="logmein-box">logmein</div>
  <div id="createme-box">createme</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {width:600px; height:500px; background-color:#F60;}
#logmein-box {display:none; width:400px; height:400px; background-color:#F20;}
#createme-box {display:none; width:400px; height:400px; background-color:#567;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#logmein").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $(".logmein-box").slideToggle(200);
  if(this).hasClass("test");
  return;
  $(this).addClass("test");
    $(".createme-box").hide();
});
```

i also made a codepen - fiddle was offline.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mHGbJ

EDIT: i end up using this code - can anyone make a shorter smarter approach with the same output?

```
$('#login-slide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $('#user-box').slideUp(function () {
                $('#login-slide').addClass('selected');
                $('#user-slide').removeClass('selected');
                $('#login-box').slideDown();
            });
        }
    });
//here is 2 buttons because i need to enter new user from two buttons.
    $('#user-slide, .lab-key-continue-btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $('#login-box').slideUp(function () {
                $('#user-slide').addClass('selected');
                $('#login-slide').removeClass('selected');
                $('#user-box').slideDown();
            });
        }
    });




});
```

The selected class is just for a background color on my nav button so i can see which is active.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/54Xyu/

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first glance I can tell you that you need to change `(".logmein-box")` into `("#logmein-box")`. Note the hashtag instead of period since it is an `ID` and not a `CLASS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="user">
 <li id="action_login">login</li>
 <li id="action_create">new user</li>
</ul><div id="login" class="action">logmein</div><div id="create" class="action">createme</div>
```

then with jquery you use the following code. Also included class highlighter for the selected list element, which you can style with css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul#user li').click(function(){
    var ref = $(this).attr('id'); // 'action_login'
var divcl = ref.split('_')[0]; // 'action'
var divid = ref.split('_')[1]; // 'login'
 $( 'div.'+divcl ).css( 'display', 'none' );
 $( 'div#'+divid ).css( 'display', 'block' );
 $( 'ul#user li').removeClass( 'selected' );
 $( 'ul#user li#' + ref  ).addClass( 'selected' ).css( 'outline', 'none' ).blur();
```

});
});

Comment: you can see a working example of the same code http://jsfiddle.net/pelister/qD2S6/10/

Answer (score 0):

you have a class selector instead of id selector..

```
 $(".logmein-box").slideToggle(200);     
 ---^--- here
```

try this

```
 $("#logmein").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#logmein-box").slideDown(200);
   $("#createme-box").slideUp(200);
});

$("#createme").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#logmein-box").slideUp(200);
   $("#createme-box").slideDown(200);

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/zBdFQ/1/)